# Como ler 4 números de uma só vez, sendo que tais números devem ser separados apenas por espaço?

Tags: python-3.x

Fiz esse código mas da erro na 2° linha:

Nesse caso eu fiz essa função para resolver um problema que meu professor passou, saber se um aluno foi aprovado, reprovado, aprovado com louvor ou se vai fazer prova final. Me ajudem por favor.

```
def AnalisarSituacao():

   nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4 = float(input()) 

   mediaP= (nota1*1+nota2*2+nota3*3+nota4*4)/10

  if mediaP >=3: 
   if mediaP <7:
    print('prova final')
  if mediaP <3:
    print('reprovado')
  if mediaP >=7:
   if mediaP <9:
    print('aprovado')
  if mediaP >=9:
    print('aprovado com louvor')
```

Answer (score 0):

Para receber mais de um parâmetro através do input vocẽ pode usar:

```
    nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4 = input().split(" ")
```

Dessa maneira o console irá esperar uma entrada com 4 valores separadas por espaço.

Ex 9.0 6.2 7.3 8.0

Agora é necessário converter o tipo(de str para float), para esse caso você pode fazer diretalmente no calculo.

```
    mediaP= (float(nota1)*1+float(nota2)*2+float(nota3)*3+float(nota4)*4)/10
```

Quanto ao restante do código, fique atento a indentação.

pS.: Talvez você possa refinar um pouco essa árvore de decisão.

Comment: faltou chamar o input - esse codigo vai dar erro. `input().split()` é o certo.

Comment: Verdade @jsbueno. Errei na hora de colocar aqui. Vou editar.

Answer (score 0):

Seu código pode ser escrito assim:

```
def analisar_situacao(media):
    if media < 3:
        print('Reprovado')
    elif media < 7:
        print('Prova final')
    elif media < 9:
        print('Aprovado')
    else:
        print('Aprovado com louvor')


nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4 = map(float, input().split())

m = (nota1 + nota2 * 2 + nota3 * 3 + nota4 * 4) / 10

analisar_situacao(m)
```

Comment: O que você acha de explicar melhor está fazendo para quem está começando conseguir entender?  Explicar o que faz o split, o que faz o map, por que o jeito que o AP tentou fazer o input não funciona sozinho, etc... ficaria legal!